# Sci-Fi Book about people living underground after World War 3

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I read a short excerpt from this book on a state exam (MCAS) maybe 10 or so years ago. The premise is that people live in underground tunnels after World War 3, tunnels that had previously been used as shelter from the fallout from the war. The only other thing I remember from it is that the main character is a young boy and he's checking out some plants that are growing underground.

Anyone think they know it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This](http://www.scholastic.com/content/collateral_resources/pdf/43/9780545184243.pdf) (see page 30) is the "excerpt" you're referring to.

The lack of any author attribution, as well as the lack of a separate copyright on the paper itself strongly leads me to think that this is an *original* short story by the paper's author, [Michael Priestly](http://www.goodreads.com/author/show/173161.Michael_Priestley) rather than an excerpt from a larger story or book.

> A meteor drove us underground—an enormous rock that hurtled through
>   space and landed somewhere in the Nevada desert. We knew the meteor
>   was coming because the scientists had spotted it through their
>   telescopes, but there was nothing we could do. When the meteor landed,
>   the climate would change drastically. It would become cold and dark,
>   and the air would become too dirty to breathe. There was no escape, so
>   we could only sit by and await our doom. Then, without much time to
>   spare, someone got the brilliant idea of going underground

This is backed up by the fact that **none** of the other articles can be found elsewhere, other than in links that lead back different versions of the papers.

Comment: Thank so much for finding that! The fact there's no book may be why I could never find it.

Comment: @wikis - Lack of proof isn't proof of lack. For all we know, the real author could turn up and demand recognition or We could find out that he used a ghost writer.

Answer (score -1):

I can only thin about Metro game series, when it comes to this topic :P

Comment: Welcome, can you provide some plot points that made you think of that series?